Creating an editable library in Python
Using Python 3.11 and I'm following this guide
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html and https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout in which I have a project and I can use it as an editable library.
The library has this structure:
\library:
    \Include
    \Lib
    \Scripts
    \src:
       \ry:
           __init__.py (this is empty)
           tests.py (this has one function)
    pyproject.toml
    pyvenv.cfg
    README.md

pyproject.toml looks like this
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]

[project]
name = "ry"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = [
  { name="Jorge", email="myname@emaildomain.com" },
]
description = "A small example package"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]

Then I have a test venv environment that I activate then cd to \library and I can call
>python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --editable .

I and get it successfully installed; however, in the test venv I have a testLibrary.py that can't reference the library. I try:
import ry
or
from ry import tests

No matter what I tried I can't get the ry referenced in the test venv.
Any idea what's wrong?
Thanks

That should just work. What happens when you try to import ry from an interactive python session? ie. >>> import ry; print(ry.__file__). What is the output of python -m site? It should output a list of strings, one of which is a path to your virtual environment. Finally, how are you calling your testLibrary.py, have you activate the venv in that shell too?

Wait, hang on, why do you have a pyvenv.cfg and a Scripts in the root of your project? Sounds like you may have setup your virtual environment in a strange way.

Thank you @Dunes. The init.py file had an extra space at the begging of the line.
I'm trying to make the Library a project itself and that's why it has its own Scripts and other items; so ideally, I would add libraries to it so it has it's own environment
I was also looking at the editor in Visual Studio and for some reason when I do import ry the ry gets undelined with green and it doesn't show in autofill. Anyway, that's secondary because when I ran from interactive Python window it works.

The ry in Visual Studio gets flagged with 'ReportsMissingImports'. It still runs fine, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a line in pyproject.toml.
